# Parent and child of fork() in C

Tags: c, process, fork

Since each process is doing its own thing, which to me feels more like a "brothers/sisters" relationship. Is there a specific reason behind calling them parent process and child process?

Also, is it true that the parent process always run before the child process?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by second part of the question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: 1. child is created by parent. 2. no.

Comment: @mike.dld I have a code that simply prints "parent" and "child" for each correspoding process, and "parent" always gets printed first though?

Comment: @LesbianSquirtle Just a coincidence I believe, check out below answers. On other systems with other schedulers the order could change. It could even change on the same system depending on whether the time slice is close to an end at the time `fork()` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The parent owns the process group and thus spawns and reaps the children. Usually this process does a little bit of administrative work, while the children act as peers and siblings.

The naming is just convention for describing which process spawned the other, though.

Comment: There're also some cases where it's not only the convention. For example, `waitpid()` refuses to work if calling process is not a parent of passed `pid`, returning `ECHILD` error.

Comment: @mike.dld Yeah, that's what I meant by spawn & reap. Typing on a crappy device :) pls feel free to edit the answer to be more thorough or write one out and I'll delete :)

Answer (score 0):

The parent process and child process does the work based on your code but not because of parent or child relationship. When you execute fork() in the main thread it will create a child process, here the fork returns a value which is different in parent process and child process which can be used to differentiate the work of parent and child processes accordingly. 
fork() always return pid of child in parent process and 0 in child process.

Coming to your second question it always depends on the scheduler as soon as the fork() is called and we cannot predict which process gets to run first after fork() function call.

Comment: I have a code that simply prints "parent" and "child" for each correspoding process, and "parent" always gets printed first though?

Comment: After calling of the fork() your parent is getting CPU time and hence it is getting executed and later the child is getting the CPU time. If you want your child to run first and then parent you can use vfork() which will make child and parent run in a synchronized manner. The consequences after fork() call are entirely dependent on the scheduler only.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a specific reason behind calling them parent process and child process?

Well, since it one process (the parent) that creates the second one (the child), that might be  the reasoning for the naming.

> Also, is it true that the parent process always run before the child process?

The short answer. Nope.
I have been using this in all of my C-code

```
pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0){ // child     
    // Child stuff
  }else{ // parent
    // Parent stuff
}
```

You might also want to use the

```
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fork()` creates a copy of the *current* process which is a part of the process control group. The new process is subordinate to the originating process, for example when a *child* process dies, SIGCHLD is sent to the parent. Also, the clone is an inferior copy: for instance, any stored `getpid()` results will be inaccurate in the child; the child has a different `parentid`, the child has *copies* of the parent's file descriptors, and has independent resource usage counters.

The parent process, then, is always the one that made the call to `fork()`, if that's what you mean by run first. If you mean "will the scheduler always give the parent process slices first" then the answer is no.

See: http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c694/lectures/ForksThreads/forks.html, http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    pid_t otherPid;

    printf("parent pid = %u\n", getpid());

    otherPid = fork();
    // in the parent, otherPid = the child's (new) process ID
    // in the child, otherPid = 0.

    switch (otherPid) {
        case -1:
            printf("Fork failed: %d\n", errno);
            return errno;
        break;
        case 0: // child
            sleep(2);
            printf("child: my pid is %u\n", getpid());
        break;
        default:
            printf("parent: pid is %u, child should have %u\n", getpid(), otherPid);
            sleep(3);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should use C syntax, not C++, cause this is C tag.

Comment: Strange that it showed up under the C++ tag then. Modified.

Answer (score 0):

Parents are always before child. Sort and sweet!!!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The question is " is it true that the parent process always run before the child process?" so I replay in sort.

Comment: No, the question was `Is there a specific reason behind calling them parent process and child process?`. Please try to read the whole text, not only the title and ending. The question you just quoted was a side question. Your answer, if it is an intended answer (and not just chatty half-joke-half-truth), is not clear. Try to elaborate it a bit more. If you meant "are - before" in terms of social/evolutionary reference - write it so. If you mean "before" in terms of "watch/protect" - write it so. And if you don't feel like writing long&clear - why write at all if there already are good answers?